# VB.NET - NullReferenceException Unhandled

Tags: vb.net, unhandled

Usually I handle my bugs by myself but this time I need help of experts!
This never happened to me, and the less data one has (usually) the less you can say what happened.

I am trying to write a simple query analyser. I randomly receive these kind of crashes:

1) I am starting with the following function:

```
Dim thd As New Thread(AddressOf StartSub)
thd.Start()
```

then the Startsub follows:

```
 Public Sub StartSub()
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    txtExecution.Text = "Executing query..."
    Dim query As String = QueryBuilder()
    UpdateView(query)
End Sub
```

and then the updateview updates the datagrid I have:

```
    Dim da As New SqlCeDataAdapter(query, connStr)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Try
        da.Fill(dt)
        txtExecution.Text = "Query executed successfully."
        dgTickets.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        txtExecution.Text = "Query failed."
        tbGrid.BeginInvoke(Sub() tbGrid.SelectedTab = tbGrid.TabPages(1))
    End Try
```

2) The code crashes in UpdateQuery on the following line (debugger does not say that it crashes here, I guessed it by selecting all lines and going through it 1 by 1):

```
dgTickets.DataSource = dt
```

3) What the debugger says:
NullReferenceException was unhandled(...)
use the new keyword to create an object instance

stack trace:

```
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetEditedFormattedValue(Object value, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewCellStyle& dataGridViewCellStyle, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.PaintWork(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.PaintCells(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle rowBounds, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates rowState, Boolean isFirstDisplayedRow, Boolean isLastVisibleRow, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle rowBounds, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates rowState, Boolean isFirstDisplayedRow, Boolean isLastVisibleRow)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintRows(Graphics g, Rectangle boundingRect, Rectangle clipRect, Boolean singleHorizontalBorderAdded)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintGrid(Graphics g, Rectangle gridBounds, Rectangle clipRect, Boolean singleVerticalBorderAdded, Boolean singleHorizontalBorderAdded)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at SQLquery.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
```

This is pretty vague actually. The file specified above does not exist. The place where it crashes is wrapped with Try-End Try. Moreover, yes, I have the painting event set up but it should not concern it (or maybe it does?).

I would really appreciate very very much any hints as far as this one. I have to add that I use visual basic express edition. The error occurs ocasionally - sometimes when I'm lucky nothing happens, and when I'm not then I get this crash.

Pete.

Comment: Why are you deliberately disabling the cross-thread illegal access call? While it's not clear whether or not that *is* the problem, it's certainly not a good idea...

Comment: Where does `dgTickets` get set?

Comment: +1 for writing a complete and thorough question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never touch/update any GUI controls inside background threads. So lines like:

```
txtExecution.Text = "Executing query..."
```

and

```
dgTickets.DataSource = dt
```

inside a background thread are doomed to fail. This should always be done on the main GUI thread using `Control.BeginInvoke`.

The only GUI update that you seem to be doing correctly is this `tbGrid` in the `catch`:

```
tbGrid.BeginInvoke(Sub() tbGrid.SelectedTab = tbGrid.TabPages(1))
```

You should read about [UI WinForms thread invokes](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/pages/126345.aspx).